# Appending an item to an array is overriding the previous items and add a new one

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am having an issue appending items to an array. I am using Alamofire and the Open Weather API to get these items.

Getting the JSON response and parsing its not a problem. Adding the first item to the array also works fine.

Example of the items :

> Date         : Monday 
>  High Temp    : 85F 
>  Low Temp     :
>   72F 
>  Weather Type : Rain
>
> Date         : Tuesday 
>  High Temp    : 102F 
>  Low Temp     :
>   97F 
>  Weather Type : Sunny
>
> Date         : Wednesday 
>  High Temp    : 98F 
>  Low Temp     :
>   62F 
>  Weather Type : Rain
>
> Date         : Thursday 
>  High Temp    : 95F 
>  Low Temp     :
>   92F 
>  Weather Type : Cloudy
>
> Date         : Friday 
>  High Temp    : 83F 
>  Low Temp     :
>   77F 
>  Weather Type : Sunny
>
> Date : Saturday 
>  High Temp : 100F 
>   Low Temp : 85F 
>  Weather Type : Sunny

These are store in a **WeatherForecast** object which in turn are added/appended to the **WeatherForecasts** array.

The problem is that what ends up happening is the last value being in this case
Saturday ends up filling all six elements in the array.

Using a for loop I notice it went like this.

Added first item correctly, then add the second items twice overriding the first item. Then the third item overrides the first and the second items ... repeat until end.

What happens using numbers : 
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666 <- final result, last element is repeat it 6 times.

What I want :
123456

My code follows :

```
class WeatherService
{
    private var weatherForecasts: [WeatherForecast] = [WeatherForecast]();
    private var weatherForecast: WeatherForecast = WeatherForecast();
    private var arrayOfInts: [Int] = [Int]();
    private var counter: Int = 0;

    public func downloadWeatherForecast(getForecastURL: String,
                completed: @escaping(_ weatherPayload: WeatherPayload) -> Void)
    {
        Alamofire.request(getForecastURL)
                 .responseJSON
        {
            response in

            let result = response.result;

            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            {
                if let list = dict["list"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                {

                    for dictItem in list
                    {
                        if let temp = dictItem["temp"] as? Dictionary<String, Double>
                        {

                            if let maxTemp = temp["max"]
                            {
                                self.weatherForecast.setHighTemp(highTemp: self.convertToString(temp: maxTemp));
                            }

                            if let minTemp = temp["min"]
                            {
                                self.weatherForecast.setLowTemp(lowTemp: self.convertToString(temp: minTemp));
                            }
                        }

                        if let weatherArray = dictItem["weather"] as?
                            [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                        {
                            if let main = weatherArray[0]["main"] as? String
                            {
                                self.weatherForecast.setWeatherType(weatherType: main.capitalized);
                            }
                        }

                        if let date = dictItem["dt"] as? Double
                        {
                            let convertedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date);
                            self.weatherForecast.setDate(date: convertedDate.dayOfWeek()!);
                        }

                        self.counter += 1;
                        self.arrayOfInts.append(self.counter);
                        self.weatherForecasts.append(self.weatherForecast);
                    }

                    //Array of ints works fine.
                    for integer in self.arrayOfInts
                    {
                        print("Int val is : \(integer)");
                    }
                }
                completed(self.retrievalSuccess(weatherForecasts: self.weatherForecasts));
            }
            else
            {
                completed(self.retrievalFailure(message: "Six day forecast error."));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using append using an arrayOfInts and it works fine, there is no overriding which has me stumped as to what is the problem with my **WeatherForecasts** array.

Comment: Most probably, `WeatherForecast` is a *class* (a reference type), and you are always modifying and appending the *same instance.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that weatherForecast is added several times to your array.
Lets say you weatherForecast name is 'X'
Your code does this:

1st iteration:

```
X.day = "Monday"
forecasts.add(X)
//forecasts is now [X]
```

then if you print all forecasts days it will print "Monday"

2nd iteration:

```
X.day = "Tuesday"
forecasts.add(X)
//forecasts is now [X,X]
```

3rd iteration:

```
X.day = "Wednesday"
forecasts.add(X)
//forecasts is now [X,X,X]
```

if you print all forecasts days.. it will print "Wednesday,Wednesday,Wednesday"

**This happens because you are referencing the same object and updating it**.. what **you need to do is create a new object on each iteration** so that your array looks like this [X,Y,Z] instead of [X,X,X]

try changing this part of your code:

```
for dictItem in list {
```

for this:

```
for dictItem in list {
    weatherForecast = WeatherForecast()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new WeatherForecast object each time while iterate array

```
class WeatherService {
    private var weatherForecasts: [WeatherForecast] = [WeatherForecast]()

    public func downloadWeatherForecast(getForecastURL: String, completed: @escaping(_ weatherPayload: WeatherPayload) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(getForecastURL).responseJSON { response in
            if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                if let list = dict["list"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                    for dictItem in list {
                        var weatherForecast = WeatherForecast()
                        if let temp = dictItem["temp"] as? Dictionary<String, Double> {
                            if let maxTemp = temp["max"] {
                                weatherForecast.setHighTemp(highTemp: self.convertToString(temp: maxTemp));
                            }

                            if let minTemp = temp["min"] {
                                weatherForecast.setLowTemp(lowTemp: self.convertToString(temp: minTemp));
                            }
                        }

                        if let weatherArray = dictItem["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                            if let main = weatherArray[0]["main"] as? String {
                                weatherForecast.setWeatherType(weatherType: main.capitalized);
                            }
                        }

                        if let date = dictItem["dt"] as? Double {
                            let convertedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date);
                            weatherForecast.setDate(date: convertedDate.dayOfWeek()!);
                        }

                        self.arrayOfInts.append(self.counter);
                        self.weatherForecasts.append(weatherForecast);
                    }
                }
                completed(self.retrievalSuccess(weatherForecasts: self.weatherForecasts));
            } else {
                completed(self.retrievalFailure(message: "Six day forecast error."));
            }
        }
    }
}
```